# Navigation Bar Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to have a navigation bar that can navigate into 3 pages (Home, Profile, and Favorites). I follow a course online, somehow it didn't list the file that normally other people do to navigate (example: List  _pages = [Home(),Profile()]).

I try to create the list with all the context inside however I got an error on the 'widget' saying that it can't be access in a initalizer.

Since the code is connected to the Firebase, removing 'user widget.user' will lose all the data of the current user such as the their favorites food.

[image: The Error]

Is there a way to change the body in the Home.dart so that it can navigate to multiple pages since the code below is only ideal for 2 pages (ItemList & ProfileScreen) to navigates.

Home.Dart

```
 class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function logOut;
  final User user;
  HomeScreen({@required this.logOut, @required this.user});
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int currentItem = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Order Je!',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: MainColors.whiteColor,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: currentItem == 1
          ? ProfileScreen(
              logout: () {
                widget.logOut();
              },
            )
          : ItemList(user: widget.user),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavBar(
        currentSelectedItem: (value) {
          setState(() {
            currentItem = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Custom Nav

```
class CustomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int) currentSelectedItem;
  CustomNavBar({@required this.currentSelectedItem});
  @override
  _CustomNavBarState createState() => _CustomNavBarState();
}

class _CustomNavBarState extends State<CustomNavBar> {
  int selectedItem = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CurvedNavigationBar(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: 52,
      backgroundColor: MainColors.primaryColor,
      animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 350),
      index: selectedItem,
      onTap: (currItem) {
        setState(() {
          selectedItem = currItem;
          widget.currentSelectedItem(currItem);
        });
      },
      items: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.home),
        Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        Icon(Icons.favorite)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry for asking such stupid question. I'm new in Flutter and Firebase development.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you problem, I would suggest you to not split the Home and the navigation bar components, Kindly take a look into this, it will help you

[Google Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Comment: SURYA Please explain the code. Giving a link as an answer may promote moderator to delete your answer.

Comment: Yes Thankyou, but I have mentioned what can be avoided, the method he is doing it is always fine, so just pointing him to try an alternative method :)

Comment: SURYA: One of my answer got deleted by the moderator for doing the same thing, so I am just cautioning you that's it. They expect us to answer to the question. Even if you just give the code without explanation you may receive comments or votedown which will cause you to lose reputation points. I am just sharing my experience. Since you are new first try and get bronze badges, it will help you understand how Stack Overflow works.. I am just suggesting. By getting more reputation points new privileges will be unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

We can use widget keyword when we want to refer to the method defined in the stateful class not in the state.

To solve this:
You can pass user and logout method to the state of the class.

```
@override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState(logOut,user);
```

and in the state create a constructor

```
final Function logOut;
final User user;
_HomeScreenState(this.logOut,this.user);
```

Hope this will help you and can you please upload the error that it is giving.